# Use of moved value `inb`

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a function, and I'm getting an error message about borrowing that I can't solve because I'm struggling to wrap my head around other responses on this site. Here's the function I've got so far:

```rust
use orgize::Org;

fn convert(i: String) -> String {
    let inb: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    Org::parse_string(i).write_html(inb);
    let out = String::from_utf8(inb).unwrap();
    return out;
}
```

And it's outputting the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `inb`
 --> src/main.rs:9:30
  |
7 |  let inb: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
  |      --- move occurs because `inb` has type `Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
8 |  Org::parse_string(i).write_html(inb);
  |                                  --- value moved here
9 |  let out = String::from_utf8(inb).unwrap();
  |                              ^^^ value used here after move
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `write_html(inb)`, you are *moving* `inb`. It cannot be used anymore.

Since [`write_html()`](https://docs.rs/orgize/latest/orgize/struct.Org.html#method.write_html) accepts a generic `W: Write`, and [`Vec<u8>` implements `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.67.0/src/std/io/impls.rs.html#381-413) but also [any `&mut Write` implements `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.67.0/src/std/io/impls.rs.html#54-84), you can just pass `&mut inb` to *borrow* `inb` instead of *moving* it:

```rust
fn convert(i: String) -> String {
    let mut inb: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    Org::parse_string(i).write_html(&mut inb);
    let out = String::from_utf8(inb).unwrap();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: That explains why the call looked so strange.

Comment: Thank you so much for being patient with me.